# MSAL login swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

Im trying to use Azure ADB2C to login. Unfortunately I get error which cant find why Im getting the error. This is my entire code for implementing the login in Swiftui. This is the error - **"Error Domain=MSALErrorDomain Code=-50000 "(null)" UserInfo={MSALErrorDescriptionKey=parentViewController has no window! Provide a valid controller with view and window., MSALInternalErrorCodeKey=-42000}"**.
Thank you for your help.

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         loadView()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    func loadView() {
        do {
            let authority =
                try MSALB2CAuthority(
                    url: URL(
                        string: "https://Kauthority/b2c_1_susi"
                    )!
                )
            let pcaConfig = MSALPublicClientApplicationConfig(
                clientId: "MyClientID",
                redirectUri: nil,
                authority: authority
            )
            pcaConfig.knownAuthorities = [authority]
            let application = try MSALPublicClientApplication(configuration: pcaConfig)
            let webViewParameters = MSALWebviewParameters(authPresentationViewController: self)
            let interactiveParameters = MSALInteractiveTokenParameters(
                 scopes: ["user.read"],
                webviewParameters: webViewParameters
            )

            application.acquireToken(with: interactiveParameters) { result, error in
                guard let result = result else {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }

                if let account = result.account.identifier {

                    **Note: what should I put here since 'windows' will be 
                      deprecated in iOS 15.0**

                        UIApplication.shared.windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }!
                            .rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())               
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my UIViewControllerRepresentable class

```
struct LoginUIViewRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> LoginViewController {
        LoginViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_: UIViewControllerType, context _: Context) {}
}
```

Here is my ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
     LoginUIViewRepresentable()
    }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to successfully implement MSAL with SwiftUI? I'm facing several issues with this at the moment.